# Error cs0120 when I try to use nameof in an attribute initialization

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
[Index(Type = IndexType.Persistent,
    Fields = new []{ nameof(Guid) })]
class MyEntity 
{
   public string Guid { get; set; }
   ... other fields
}
```

But sometimes I have the following:

```
class MyEntity 
{
   public string Guid { get; set; }
   public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
}  

class MetaData 
{
   public string MetaGuid { get; set; }
}
```

And all I need to do is something like:

```
[Index(Type = IndexType.Persistent,
    Fields = new []{ nameof(MetaData) + "." nameof(MetaData.MetaGuid)})]
class MyEntity 
{
   public string Guid { get; set; }
   public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
}
```

to get the following string: "MetaData.MetaGuid".

Of course, `nameof(MetaData.MetaGuid)` does not work. It gives me [Compiler Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120).

Any ideas how can I get the name of `MetaGuid` inside

```
[Index(Type = IndexType.Persistent,
    Fields = new []{ <THIS PLACE>})]
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler assumes you are referencing the property on the type that attribute is placed on (`MetaData`), that resolves first over the external type `MetaData`. You need to qualify the type with a namespace and then it will resolve correctly. See the code below and replace `NameSpaceHere` with the namespace where the `MetaData` type is placed.

```
[Index(Type = IndexType.Persistent,
    Fields = new []{ nameof(NameSpaceHere.MetaData) + "." + nameof(NameSpaceHere.MetaData.MetaGuid)})]
class MyEntity 
{
   public string Guid { get; set; }
   public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
}
```